# Is there a way to unmarshall an array inside an object directly into a list using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have a very simple JSON:

```json
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "name": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "Apple"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can unmarshall this JSON easily using the default ObjectMapper that comes with Java and two simple POJO classes which look like this:

```java
public class FruitList {

    private List<Fruit> fruits;

    public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
        return fruits;
    }

    public void setFruits(List<Fruit> fruits) {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }

}
```

And the individual Fruit elements:

```java
public class Fruit {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

This works and is perfectly acceptable. However, I would like to know it it is possible to unmarshal this JSON directly into a `List<Fruit>` - somehow ignoring the container object called fruits?

I tried using this feature but it did not work:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Also experimenting with:

```java
List<Fruit> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Fruit.class));
```

Did not do the trick.

Thanks for any help,
Cheers

Comment: List<Fruit> listCar = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Fruit>>(){});

Comment: That does not work. It gives error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Oh yes cause your json is not a list but an object containing the list in the fruits field. If your son would be [...] then the thing I suggested would work.

Comment: FruitList fruitList = objectMapper.readValue(json, FruitList.class); 
List<Fruit>  list = fruitList.getFruits();

Maybe that?